# Camera Lense overlay - WindowsRT

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm creating an app where I would like the user to be able to take their own photos.  However, I'd like to apply an overlay of where the face should be in the picture (in order for the app to work best).

So when the camera is launched from the app, I'd like there to be a faint outline that is visible on the screen.  This way the user can line up the face inside of that outline.

Where would I even look to see how that is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [with MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b)  or [with the Nokia Developer's library](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!imaging/advanced-photo-capturing.html)

Nokia just released an [Imaging SDK for Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk.html) which might be useful.